# Configure liquibase to ignore MD5SUM

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm currently updating a liquibase conf to springboot 2

long story short: I don't have any way to know what the previous version or configuration was.

I only have the script and the previous databaselock , which I want to continue with

My issue is the previous database lock column `MD5SUM` is **empty**. BUT my new liquibase fill the MD5SUM column.

So when I launch liquibase, it try to run all the oldest script; because he think they never run, because of the empty `MD5SUM`.

How can I configure liquibase to not fill `MD5SUM`?
(I use spring boot and CorisqSpringLiquibase)

Comment: I am assuming that when you say `databaselock` you actually mean the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table, because that is where there is an MD5SUM column. The MD5SUM column in that table is central to the operation of Liquibase, so if that column is empty then something has altered it outside of liquibase. If you know that all the changesets have been deployed, you can use the `changeLogSync` command to populate the column with the correct values.

Comment: Sound like a good idea ! I will try-it. Any idea why the M5DSUM can be empty? (new script added still don't have m5DSUm)

Comment: What were the exact steps/command you used to add the new script? If you used `liquibase update` then I can't think of a way for that not to get filled in, unless something is mis-configured and the DATABASECHANGELOG table you are looking at is in a different database or schema or something like that. You can also use --logLevel=debug to get more information on what is happening.

Comment: I use the default spring boot liquibase bean, no specific config added.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about spring boot to help you.

Comment: Epilogue : I have regenerate the checksum, and now my new config work fine and cleanly . Thanks  !

Comment: Good to hear! You should write up an answer to your own question that includes everything that you did to help others that come after us.